# How to redirect to html page after AJAX get request

Tags: java, ajax, spring-restcontroller

Part of `index.html` file :

```
 <button id="getAllGroups" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Groups</button>
```

Then my `js` file :

```
GET: $(document).ready(
function () {

    // GET REQUEST
    $("#getAllGroups").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        ajaxGet();
    });

    // DO GET
    function ajaxGet() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "checkGroups",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.status == "success") {
                     var custList = "";
                    $.each(result.data,
                        function (i, group) {

                            var Html = "<tr>" +
                            "<td>" + group.groupId + "</td>" +
                            "<td>" + group.groupName + "</td>" +
                            "</tr>";
                            console.log("Group checking: ", group);
                            $('#tbody').append(Html);
                        });
                    console.log("Success: ", result);
                    window.location.href = "groupsPagik"
                } else {
                    console.log("Fail: ", result);
                }
            },             
        });
    }
})
```

And my RestController :

```
@RestController
public class GroupController {


@Autowired
GroupService groupService;
@GetMapping("/checkGroups")
public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllGroups() {
    ServiceResponse<List<Group>> response = new ServiceResponse<>("success", groupService.getAll());
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Everything good and if I print obtained data to the same page - `index.html` :

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <table border="2">
            <thead>
            <th>Group Id</th>
            <th>Group name</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tbody">

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I want to print this data ( groups ) to new html page.
So this is my question how to do it : print obtained data not to the same page, but to another.

Comment: Hi, if you need to print on other page then why you are using ajax ?

Comment: @Swati Maybe it is my mistake for printing to other page, but I need to use AJAX and do this project on AJAX, so maybe I don't need to redirecting to other page. 
I have also in my project students, teachers and lessons.
I was going to do it ( redirect )  because I don't know how to make it clearly and interact with all data on the same page. Can you advice smth?

Comment: You are already generating that `trs` inside success function so what is question here ? if you need it to look good use [bootstrap tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/) .